# What is an efficient way to create new dataframe column and populate values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pair of columns `"car_model"` and `"year"` that I need to send to a function as a `tuple`, and it will return me a price(float).

How to iterate over dataframe rows, send the `"car_model"` and `"year"` values to the function and add the returned value in the new column `"price"`?

I was thinking about:

```
model_year = CAR[["car_model", "year"]]

for x in model_year.to_numpy():
    model_year_tuple = tuple(x)
    price = calculate_price(model_year_tuple)
    //how to add to the column? the line below will always use the last calculated price
    CAR['price'] = price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `apply`:

```
CAR['price'] = model_year.apply(lambda x: calculate_price(tuple(x)), axis=1)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
CAR['price'] = [calculate_price(x) for x in zip(CAR['car_model'], CAR['year'])]
```

That said, you should try rewrite your `calculate_price` function so that it accepts numpy array instead of vanilla python tuples.

Answer (score 4):

We can do

```
model_year['out'] = model_year.agg(tuple,1).map(calculate_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
 df['price'] = df.apply(lambda x: price((x['car_model'],x['year'])))
```